# How can I programmatically get various common user profile related URLs?

Tags: 8, routes

I'd like to get the following URLs in Drupal 8:

- /user/register
- /user/login
- /logout
- /user

I already know I can use `\Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath()` to get the current path. I want to build links to redirect users.

How do I get these paths programatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user URLs (or routes to be more "Drupal correct") are defined by the core user module (core/modules/user/user.routing.yml)

E.g.

```
user.register:
  path: '/user/register'
  ...

user.login:
  path: '/user/login'
  ...

user.logout:
  path: '/user/logout'
  ...

user.page:
  path: '/user'
  ...
```

So you can programmatically build links to these routes like so:

```
<?php

use Drupal\Core\Link;

// Replace user.login with other routes such as user.page
$user_login_link = Link::createFromRoute(
  t('User log in link'), // The link text
  'user.login', // The link URL generated from the route
);
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I'll still have to do `$user_login_link->getUrl();` if I want only the URL, without the markup tho.

Comment: I haven't tried this yet, but it appears you can also use `Url::fromRoute()` https://api.drupal.org/comment/61929#comment-61929